# Why did Tony Stark leave his armor to explore the castle in Sokovia?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age Of Ultron*, Tony Stark is the first member of the Avengers to get inside Baron von Strucker's castle, where he takes down a room full of soldiers before stepping out of his suit and travelling down a secret passage.

Why does he take off his suit in the middle of an enemy base when it might have protected him against Scarlet Witch's magic, or at the very least helped him better search the passageway with Jarvis' HUD?

Comment: Robert Downey Jr. needed to show his rugged, handsome self.

Comment: “One could argue that inside his armor he might have been unaffected by Scarlet Witch's magic.” One could also argue the effects would have been worse. He gets scared and suddenly launches missiles, brings down the entire base. DIDN’T THINK OF THAT, DIDJA?!?!?

Comment: @eirikdaude, you might say that in jest, but that is almost certainly the real-world answer to this question, seeing how Robert Downey Jr. has made it no secret that he wants more 'face' time in these movies.

Comment: Watching *Age of Ultron*, I literally thought as Tony was taking off the suit: “Oh, Scarlet Witch needs to get him for the narrative. That’s... showing your hand a little obviously there,” and I kind of assumed that everyone else watching thought pretty much the same thing. The needs of the narrative to have this happen fluidly trumped the needs of verisimilitude to have Tony behave realistically here.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**1. The Avengers were unaware of the second enhanced at the moment:** When Tony breached the shield and entered the castle, the Avengers knew only of "the blur". They later found out about Wanda. And since rest of the Avengers were already tackling "the blur", Tony let his guard down.

**2. Greater maneuverability/Convenience:** Tony wanted to check out the entire lab & all the computers, and the Iron Man armour isn't quite the tool to do it with. He had already run a thermal scan of the entire area, and since it was clear, he had no reason to believe he would be in any kind of danger.
He wanted to check out the computers by himself. (And after watching Iron man 3, I believe we all know how ridiculous it is when Tony tries to walk around in that armour :P)

**3. The Armour was in sentry mode:** Tony had put the armour to sentry mode, which essentially meant that he had J.A.R.V.I.S. looking out for any danger. He could summon the armour any time he needed it, as he does whilst reaching out for the scepter.

**To summarise: Tony believed himself to be in a condition safe enough to come out of the armour, considering the information that was available to them at the time.**

Comment: "any time he needed it" could be an eternity when there may be a speedster (or, since I am not sure if they identified what precisely was Quicksilver at that moment, some unknown, invisible threat) not that far from you. But it fits with Tony's carefree usual behavior.

Comment: @Taladris - over-confident more than carefree I would say... Also, The Avengers weren't entirely sure of "The Blur"s powers at the moment.

Comment: Sentry Mode turned out to be useless.

Comment: @Petersaber - well yeah... true... Tony wasn't even aware of Wanda's presence...

Comment: All good points, I still think it was a bad course of action, but it matches Tony's cocky behavior. I'll wait a bit before accepting.

Comment: @Zikato - no rush :) It was indeed a bad idea, leaving armour whilst in enemy territory. Tony should've known better.

Comment: Re #1, the Avengers were pretty dumb to think that just because they only saw one enhanced, there must only be one. That's an absolutely ridiculous reason to feel safe. And they didn't even see him at all!!!

Comment: Anyway yes the answer is that it's a lot easier to type with your own hands than it is through Iron Man hands, and with the armour standing by it really didn't do him any harm. Well, until he left it upstairs. Yay!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I've already stated in point #2 that Tony had run a thermal scan of the area and that is why he felt safe enough.

Comment: I'm agreeing with you.

Comment: Owh...Sorry... I know :-) I think my reply indicated otherwise

Comment: I just rewatched the scene and they were aware of the second enhanced. Tony finds secret room and then it cuts to Stucker surrendering to Cap who is attacked by Scarlett Witch. Cap then proceeds to inform rest of the team of the second Enhanced (Female, do not engage). Stark hears this because he responds to following message.

Comment: So when Tony enters the secret room, he's already out of the armour.... Hence, the team come to know of the second enhanced after Tony steps out of the suit...

Comment: Sentry mode isn't for "Come get me if I need it", sentry mode was covering the hostiles he had just neutralized but not killed and making sure they didn't do anything

Comment: @Stark07 his thermal scan was of the room where he left the armor not the giant chamber he entered through the passage. Had there been one guard with a gun in there he would be dead

Answer (score 59):

Stark07's answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92033/24087) is perfectly correct when at looks at the reasons from Tony's perspective about why he leaves the armour behind, but I think this is worth digging a little deeper into. Tony Stark is one of the most well developed characters not just in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, but in modern cinema today, and his relationship with his Iron Man suits is as fascinating as it is unhealthy.

If you recall the events of *Iron Man*, you will remember that Tony Stark first designs his Iron Man suit (and later refines it) in order to escape captivity in Afghanistan, where he was being held by the Ten Rings terrorists. It doesn't take many rewatches of *Iron Man* and *Iron Man 2* to see that not long after his imprisonment, he begins to suffer from PTSD (post-traumatic stress disorder) - simply look at his actions in the films, almost all of which are motivated by a greater need to "take control".

By the time *Iron Man 3* rolls around, Tony Stark is in a worse state than ever after flying through the portal in *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*. It is here we see his PTSD at it's worst state - he is quite literally a mess, having panic attacks if asked to recall the events of New York and spending increasingly large amounts of time building more Iron Man suits, to the point where it is putting strain on his relationship with Pepper Potts.

The events of *Iron Man 3*, which leave Tony suitless and force him to rely on himself rather than the suits for the first time since Afghanistan go a long way to easing some of the worries he faces - most importantly, that HE is Iron Man, not the suit. The end result of this is that by the time *Avengers: Age of Ultron* rolls around, we find ourselves in the company of the most mentally sound version of Tony Stark we have seen since his first appearance in *Iron Man* - at least until Scarlet Witch interacts with him.

**Tony Stark's PTSD and his new found ability to cope with it is the reason that he takes off the suit in Baron von Strucker's base.** It's a way of showing the audience that Tony Stark isn't as reliant on the suits as he once was - that he is "better", so to speak. He feels confident that he is relatively safe without the suit, and as such he leaves it behind - but not too far behind. He is Iron Man after all.

Comment: “He feels confident that he is relatively safe without the suit, and as such he leaves it behind” — yup. Then he has one hallucination and goes full-pelt towards surrounding the entire earth with Iron Men. *TONYYYY*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That's actually one of the things I love about *Avengers: Age of Ultron*. Tony doesn't magically get over PTSD - he learns to liveand cope with it, and we see that it can be retriggered.

Comment: I disagree because of a couple of things. In Iron man 1, Tony shows a similar careless behaviour while fighting Obadiah. He throws off his gauntlet, which indicates that he is feeling like getting the armour off. He also lets his guards down after blowing up the missiles, when he gets shot at by a tank. There are numerous such incidents from which we could conclude that Tony has had a habit of this, and it isn't a symbol of his fading dependence on his armoury.

Comment: @Stark07 When Tony takes off his gauntlet he thought he had won the fight at that point due to the icing problem to be fair - he was also running on very low power, and the suit was becoming nearly useless to him. As for the  tank, he was flying away from an active war zone after he believed he had completed his mission - he remained in the suit, only getting shot because he was taken by surprise by an enemy a very long distance away, one that he was unaware of.

Comment: What about giving his address to Mandarin and then be surprised by the attack?

Comment: @Zikato His good friend Happy Hogan had just been put in the hospital by The Mandarin, and Tony was looking for a confrontation. Giving out his address was certainly reckless and self-destructive - ["Arousal and reactive symptoms may include being irritable and angry outbursts; behaving recklessly or in a self-destructive way"](http://www.psychiatry.org/ptsd), so it quite happily fits in with the diagnosis.

Comment: Tony isn't a trained fighter like Rogers or Barton or Odinson (:P). He isn't entirely careful at all times. And I must disagree about his reliance on suits. Even in IM3, right after Maya walks in, he steps out of his suit. Just like that, without a second thought. And he was under imminent threat at that time as well. He also sent the Mark 42 to save Pepper first, rather than himself. His PTSD wasn't manifesting as a dependency on the suits. It was more about having backup, having more options. And that manifested as his feverish suit building.

Comment: @Stark07 His PTSD absolutely **was** manifesting as dependancy on the suits, and not just in *Iron Man 3* - take another look at *Iron Man 2*, such as when he gets incredibly drunk in his suit or when he hangs out on the donut in his suit. In *Iron Man 3* the problem has got so bad that he develops new technology to call the suit to him at any time, as well as creating one that is activated in his sleep and attacks Pepper, which is when he is at his worst. I'll agree that part of it was about having back-ups and options, but that is still dependancy on the suits.

Comment: @Stark07 Also - "He also sent the Mark 42 to save Pepper first, rather than himself". I believe that was the first part of the healing process for Tony - he realised that when someone is relying on him, he is more than capable of putting someone elses needs before his own, which started the self-confidence boost that culminated in him willingly destroying the many suits he had created as he realises that the suit doesn't make the man - HE is Iron Man.

Comment: He got drunk in his suit basically because he was showing off. He had no PTSD in IM2. He hangs out in the donut in the suit because he flew there in it! Think of it like driving up to some place and then eating whilst in your car. He was creating the automated suit because that was the next logical step. He had already made a prototype in Avengers. Even *before* the PTSD(Scene where Loki throws him out the window). He was already working on it. The part where it gets activated in sleep.. Well file a bug for that...

Comment: Also his suit building spree was a result of *LOTS* of spare time! Pepper was the CEO, Happy was in-charge of security. He had nothing else at hand. It literally was his hobby. And after New York, he was wary of being outnumbered. That was the motivation behind building lots of suits.

Comment: If he had the remotely operated suits during the attack of New York, he could've sent the missile with a drone instead of going through the whole *Trauma* in the first place. Which is why he built those things first.

Comment: @Stark07 This is getting pretty lengthy and unsuitable for comments - but **Tony Stark definitely has PTSD in *Iron Man 1* and *Iron Man 2*.** This is a man who was blown up, tortured, and shown his life work was in the hands of his enemies, before being forced to kill multiple people in order to escape - an escape that cost Yisen, the man who saved him, his life. After that we see him shut down his company, completely change his personality and begin illegally entering active war zones due to his new found need to help people.

Comment: Yeah. Then so considering all the events, all of the Avengers should have PTSD.

Comment: @Stark07 Not really. The vast majority of the rest of The Avengers haven't been through anything as traumatic, and even if they did, most of them are trained military personel that should have had at least some training in order to deal with it. Regardless, we already know that Sam Wilson runs a meeting group for those returning from war, so it isn't like the issue hasn't been addressed.

Comment: Including Bruce Banner? Or Wanda? Or Pietro? FYI, Rogers did suffer from some form of PTSD. The post-credits scene in The First Avenger certainly looks like that. And trained military personnel too can get PTSD.

Comment: @Stark07 "And trained military personnel too can get PTSD." I know that. Bruce Banner literally went into hiding out of fear of himself and his ability to hurt others - maybe knowing you cannot be harmed takes away the liklihood of PTSD developing. And Wanda and Pietro were so scarred by their experience of a war zone that they underwent experimental, highly dangerous medical procedures just to make themselves stronger. Sounds similar to Tony Stark and his need for the suits to me.

Comment: "Yeah. Then so considering all the events, all of the Avengers should have PTSD". Suffering PTSD isn't a rule. But based on what we see of their visions, they all clearly have deep rooted issues.

Answer (score 10):

Below are the answers from an out-of-universe perspective.

1) To keep the story moving forward. With the suit on, Tony Stark cannot be brainwashed or the brainwashing is less convincing to the audience. Brainwashing a suit of armor would look stupid, something Michael Bay would do.

2) Stark is the oldie and Witch is the newbie. The relationship must start very early in the movie, and it must begin human to human.

Comment: This is written from an out-of-universe perspective on good storytelling practices, but I think the question is looking for an in-universe explanation.

Comment: @Null This makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @tidwall Out of universe answers are not off topic here, unless specifically stated so in the question.

Comment: The original question did state that the OP was looking for in-universe explanations only.

Comment: @Stark07 The original question only stated that this answers first point "to allow the film to happen" isn't wanted. His second point (which could do with being expanded really) is still a valid answer.

Comment: Yeah... I don't object to the answer itself. @tidwall - The answer could do with some explanations.